# C# update XMLNS of XmlElemt

Tags: c#, xml

I have a class like:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Root", Namespace = "https://NS.com")]
public class Root
{
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "https://NS2.com")]
        public Header header { set; get; }
        public Body{ set; get; }
}
```

I serialize the `obj` to XML:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (XmlWriter wr = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(wr, obj, ns);
    }

    ms.Position = 0;
    XmlDocument doc.Load(ms);

    ms.Close();
}
```

I couldn't find any way to change the nameSpace of Root and Header to newNS, and newHeadNS. Is there a way to change namespace in the doc? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Create a new class with the same structure but new namespace and copy over?

Comment: I can't the new NS are variable and I'm getting from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `XmlAttributeOverrides` to override that.

Initialize your serializer as such :

```
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof(Root), new XmlAttributes() { XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute() { Namespace = "https://NS.new" } });
var header = new XmlAttributes();
header.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute() { Namespace = "https://NS.new/head" });
overrides.Add(typeof(Root), "Header", header);

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root), overrides);
```

And, the following to serialize :

```
serializer.Serialize(wr, obj);
```